# Why does Firebase App Distribution claim that new Android app version is downgrade?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I'm using [Firebase App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/products/app-distribution) to distribute my app for iOS and Android. For most users on iOS & Android, that worked with the latest version. But for one user, Firebase claimed that the new version was a downgrade. I'd like to know how to prevent this in the future.

The old version was "2021.6.**4** (5)", the new one "2021.6.**5** (4)". As I understand semantic versioning, the old version is less than the new one because the new one has a higher patch version: 5 vs. 4.

But Firebase begged to differ once. Below you see the installed version at the top and the new one, labeled as a "Downgrade", below. Why?

[image]

Comment: And what is the number in parentheses? I know nothing about Firebase App Distribution, but normally on Android, whether a version of an app is considered newer than another version is not based on the versionName (the user-visible string), but rather on the versionCode (which is an integer that usually isn't visible to the user).

Comment: The number at the end is the optional build number. Here's my complete version in the build file `pubspec.yaml`: `version: 2021.6.5+4` Based on [Google's documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#version), I'm using it correctly.